# PHP SDK 4.0 on Google App Engine: cURL error

Tags: php, facebook, google-app-engine, curl

I'm making a PHP application running on Google App Engine, and I'm trying to implement a Facebook Login.

After accessing to the login webpage, I am redirected to Facebook, and after I accept to log in for the application and I get redirected, I get the error "Error : Option 10065 is not supported by this curl implementation."

I have curl_lite enabled, and I'm running it on localhost for the time being. Here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Session should be active

#region Settings
$app_id             = 'xxxxxxx';  //Facebook App ID
$app_secret         = 'yyyyyyy'; //Facebook App Secret
$required_scope     = 'public_profile'; //Permissions required
$redirect_url       = 'http://localhost:8080/signup_fb.php'; //FB redirects to this page with a code
#endregion

#region Imports
//include autoload.php from SDK folder, just point to the file like this:
require_once "../libraries/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php";

//import required class to the current scope
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
#endregion

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id , $app_secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);

//try to get current user session
try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    die(" Error : " . $ex->getMessage());
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    die(" Error : " . $ex->getMessage());
}

if ($session){ //if we have the FB session
    $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
    //do stuff below, save user info to database etc.

    echo $user_profile->getProperty('name');

}else{

    //display login url 
    $login_url = $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => $required_scope ) );
    echo '<a href="'.$login_url.'">Login with Facebook</a>';
}
```

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: It complains about this row: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/4e2a74481ab97ec4dfba29530e385e510aa82e6d/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php#L180 . You will have to either change the SDK or use a real version of curl

Comment: You can enable full cURL using a php.ini file as described here. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_cURL_support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's understandable that with curl_lite enabled (curl interface backed by urlfetch and with fewer features) you would see such an issue. [Check the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_cURL_support) as another commenter mentioned, and you should definitely be using the real curl if you intend to run such specific advanced functionality with your box's devserver as the client to facebook's login flow.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I also cannot get facebook login to work with appengine, very frustrating.....

Comment: The issue was clearly explained by my answer - the functionality of "cURL lite", which uses the UrlFetch service, is not sufficient for the action the user wanted to do. For that, they should follow the docs link I supplied which explains how to enable cURL to use sockets, which is probably what's required.

Comment: [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) with a PHP runtime will have no problem running cURL as though on a virtual machine. I recommend reading about Managed VMs as well.